# Using Model Variable to Pull Feed via Feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app asks the user for their feed url address. I'm trying to pass the feed url to Feedzirra to fetch and parse the url but I'm not having any luck.

What am I doing wrong:

Here's my show method from the controller

```
# GET /scores/1
# GET /scores/1.json
def show

#@score=Score.find(params[:id])
@score = current_user.scores.find(params[:id])

url=:url
feed=Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url) 
@entry=feed.entries

respond_to do |format|
    format.html #show.html.erb
    format.json {render json: @score }
end
```

Model

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    attr_accessible :title, :postFrequency, :editorialCalendar, :postTemplate, 
    :headlineVariations, :publishingScore, :professionalLogo, :colorScheme, :typographyStandards, 
    :seoPlugin, :googleAnalytics, :setupScore, :sb_promotion_1, :sb_promotion_2, :sb_recentPosts, 
    :sidebarScore, :leadMagnet, :emailCampaign, :productCreated, :landingPage, :monetizationScore, :url,
    :name, :summary, :url, :published_at, :guid

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url  = :url
feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url)
```

Here the `url` variable will always be a symbol with its value `:url`. Don't think this is what you want.